# how does one use module.exports and require in protractor tests?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to use PageObject pattern in my e2e tests, but I am getting a message that module is not found (Error: cannot find module InsuredSearchPage)

in **/acceptance/insured/search/SearchPage.js**

I have following

```
enter code here

var InsuredSearchPage = (function () {

    'use strict';

    function InsuredSearchPage() {

        var searchButton = element(by.id(searchFormBtn));

        var page = {
            search: search
        };

        return page;

        function search() {
            searchButton.click();
        }
    }

    return InsuredSearchPage;

})();

module.exports = InsuredSearchPage;
```

and in test (that is the same folder) i have this

```
var InsuredSearchPage = require("InsuredSearchPage");
```

When I run the test, I get 'Error: cannot find module InsuredSearchPage.'  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For simple key/value pair lists you can use module.exports = { key: 'value', key2: 'value2' } in the required file without a function -- then the variable set to the require for that file will represent the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looking for `InsuredSearchPage` package in `node_modules`.  You need to specify the location of `InsuredSearchPage` *relative to the directory the file is in*:

```
var InsuredSearchPage = require("./InsuredSearchPage");
```

[The docs have more information on using `require()`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

On top of SomeKittens' answer

```
var InsuredSearchPage = require("./InsuredSearchPage");
```

I also had to change the last line in the required file from "module.exports = " to "exports.InsuredSearchPage = InsuredSearchPage"

Node 6.9.2, Protractor 4.0.13